# Como resolver o problema da posição do cursor após inserir números na máscara com JavaScript puro?

Tags: javascript, cursor

Preciso de ajuda para que o cursor fique posicionado sempre ao lado direito do número inserido. Independente da posição em que o número se encontra (antes ou depois da pontuação da máscara).

ERRO:
Atualmente, após inserir um número, voltar o cursor para digitar um novo número antes dele, ex:
digitado: 3, volto o cursor para a esquerda e digito 1 antes do 3: 13...
O cursor volta para o "final da fila", após o número 3.
O mesmo ao digitar: 32, voltar o cursor para digitar um novo número: 432. O cursor volta para o "final da fila", após o número 2.

Parte do código HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>CPF/CNPJ</label>
        <input type="text" name="cpf" style="text-align: right; direction: ltr;" class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="cpfCnpj" mask="cpfCnpj"
          [ngClass]="mostraClasseInvalido('cpfCnpj', formDadosGerais)" [attr.disabled]="cpfCnpj"
          (blur)="verificaCpfCnpj()" focus>
</div>
```

Parte do código TypeSrcipt da aplicação da máscara:

```
    import { isNullOrWhiteSpace } from 'src/app/utils/util';

function removerMascara(valor: any) {
  if (isNullOrWhiteSpace(valor)) return valor;
  else return valor.toString().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
}

export function CpfMask(event) {
  var cpf = event.target.value;
  if (cpf.length == 14) {
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 46) {
      event.cancelBubble = true;
      event.returnValue = false;
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  else {
    cpf = cpf.replace(/\D/g, "");
    cpf = cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2");
    cpf = cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2");
    cpf = cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$/, "$1-$2");
    cpf = cpf.replace(/(-\d{2})\d+?$/, "$1");
    event.target.value = cpf;
  }
}

export function CnpjMask(event) {
  var cnpj = event.target.value;
  if (cnpj.length == 18) {
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 46) {
      event.cancelBubble = true;
      event.returnValue = false;
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  else if (cnpj != null) {
    // cnpj = cnpj.replace(/\D/g, "");
    // cnpj = cnpj.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1.$2");
    // cnpj = cnpj.replace(/^(\d{2})\.(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2.$3");
    // cnpj = cnpj.replace(/\.(\d{3})(\d)/, ".$1/$2");
    // cnpj = cnpj.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/, "$1-$2");

    cnpj = cnpj.replace(/\D/g, "");
    cnpj = cnpj.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1.$2");
    cnpj = cnpj.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2");
    cnpj = cnpj.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1/$2");
    cnpj = cnpj.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/, "$1-$2");
    cnpj = cnpj.replace(/(-\d{2})\d+?$/, "$1");

    event.target.value = cnpj;
  }
}

export function CpfCnpjMask(event) {
  var cnpj = event.target.value;
  cnpj = cnpj.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
  if (cnpj.length > 14) {
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode == undefined) {
      event.target.value = '';
      event.srcElement.classList.add("error");
      setTimeout(() => {
        event.srcElement.classList.remove("error");
      }, 3000);
      return;
    }
    var controlKey = (event.ctrlKey) ? event.ctrlKey : event.ctrlKey;
    if (charCode > 46 && !controlKey) {
      event.cancelBubble = true;
      event.returnValue = false;
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  else if (cnpj != null && cnpj.length < 12) {
    CpfMask(event);
  }
  else {
    CnpjMask(event);
  }
}

export function FormatCpfCnpj(cpfCnpj: any) {
  var cnpj = cpfCnpj.replace(/\D/g, "");
  if (cnpj != null && cnpj.length < 12) {
    var cpf = cpfCnpj.replace(/\D/g, "")
    // cpf = cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2")
    // cpf = cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2")
    // cpf = cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$/, "$1-$2")
    cpf = cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2");
    cpf = cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2");
    cpf = cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$/, "$1-$2");
    cpf = cpf.replace(/(-\d{2})\d+?$/, "$1");
    return cpf;
  }
  else {
    let cnpj = cpfCnpj.replace(/\D/g, "");
    // cnpj = cnpj.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1.$2");
    // cnpj = cnpj.replace(/^(\d{2})\.(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2.$3");
    // cnpj = cnpj.replace(/\.(\d{3})(\d)/, ".$1/$2");
    // cnpj = cnpj.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/, "$1-$2");

    cnpj = cnpj.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1.$2");
    cnpj = cnpj.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2");
    cnpj = cnpj.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1/$2");
    cnpj = cnpj.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/, "$1-$2");
    cnpj = cnpj.replace(/(-\d{2})\d+?$/, "$1");
    return cnpj;
  }
}
```

Imagem do erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá @Thay! Vou fazer uma pequena crítica construtiva, talvez mais uma opinião mesmo: eu acho que essa máscara não deveria era permitir digitar um número antes do último. Por exemplo, se a pessoa precisar digitar um número anterior, ele deverá ir apagando com backspace até chegar na posição desejada, inserir o(s) número(s) e seguir novamente em frente. Seria tipo como máscara de moeda. Abs!

Comment: Obrigada! vou levar em consideração.

Comment: Estou começando a achar o problema do posicionamento do cursor esteja ligado ao uso do Replace (RegExp)..

Comment: O problema é q toda vez que vc altera o value do campo,, o cursor vai pro final.